# Вход в систему разным пользователям

Tags: python, django

```
def sign_in(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        user_login = User.objects.get(username=username)
        if user is not None:
            if user_login.teacher.get_role() == "T":
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse('Teacher')
            if user_login.student.get_role() == "S":
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse('Student')
            if user_login.parent.get_role() == "P":
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse('Parent')
        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'error': True})
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
@csrf_protect
def login(request):
    args = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            args['login_error'] = "Пользователь не найден"

        return render(request, 'login.html', args)
else:
    return render(request,'login.html', args)
```